# PCIe Kerneldriver DMA writes to incorrect addresses

Tags: linux-kernel, pci, fpga

I'm currently writing a PCIe kernel driver for linux kernel 4.19.
A FPGA (Arria 10) running an Intel DMA IP is connected to the Linux CPU (i7-6700TE) via PCIe Gen 2.
I want to run an upstream DMA transfer from FPGA to CPU RAM.
First the PCIe driver is initialized. I'm using the following instructions in order:

1. pci_enable_device
2. pci_set_master
3. pci_set_mwi
4. pci_set_dma_mask DMA_BIT_MASK(64)
5. pci_alloc_consistent

After allocation I push the physical address into the DMA configuration and start the transfer. After finishing I post a MSI, which is received and handeled.
The problem I have is that when reading the DMA data using the virtual address I only read zeros, while not writing any zeros via DMA.
I also tested the memory region by first writing a ramp to memory via CPU, then starting the DMA, then reading again and the ramp remained unchanged, thus I'm quite convinced, that no memory accesses to the specified region happened.
**Why does the MSI transfer work (address space CPU), but the RAM access doesn't?**
Do you have an idea what to do next?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

Your question is about Linux kernel programming, and so might be better suited to Stack Overflow instead. But anyway...

Have you read the [kernel DMA API HOWTO?](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt)

You said you pushed the physical address into the DMA configuration. But a DMA-capable device on the bus needs a different kind of address, since its view of the bus may be different: a "bus address". It may or may not be identical to a physical address, depending on system architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read the DMA Documentation and had the impression, that pci_alloc_consistent returns a bus address
Quote:
"It returns two values: the virtual address which you can use to access
it from the CPU and dma_handle which you pass to the card."

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I'm aware of that, but my wording was wrong, so that shouldn't be the reson for not seeing the data in the RAM... I can't really put a finger on it, but for some reason the northbridge doesn't appear to be routing the memory writes to RAM, while CPU access seems to work. Is there a possibility to debug this further? Btw... I'm using an i7-6700TE if that's helping